# async function in Python

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous

I'm new to Python, I have function1 that requires a lot of time to execute. And I call function1 from function2. But I want my function2 to execute other code rather than waiting for function1 finished.

For example:

```
def function1():
    sleep(5)
```

```
def function2():
    function1()
    return 200
```

How to let my function2 run "return 200" immediately while function1() is still running.

Thanks

Comment: Use [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) or [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html), depending on the scale of the task at hand.

Comment: Thanks, the threading way work. But can I use async way to do it? I'm just curious.

Comment: Python does have [`asyncio`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html) which you may want to look into, then.